# Pasting the first row to the column name within a list

Tags: r

I have 68 data files- all with the same identifiers-but with different indicators. I converted these individual files into a list with each data frame as a separate element. 
The first row of every data frame is a year, which I would like to paste to the column name. I want to be able to separate it by "_". 
For example, right now the column name is Arbeitslose, and the row under it has 2018. I would like the column name to become Arbeitslose_2018.

I know how to do this on a single data frame. The code I used is below.

```
RAW_2[1,] <- as.character(RAW_2[1,]) # Converting the fist row to a character. 
colnames(RAW_2) <- paste(colnames(RAW_2),RAW_2[1, ], sep = "_") # Paste Year (Row 2) and columnname 
RAW_2 <- RAW_2[rownames(RAW_2) != 1, ] # Drop 1st row which is the years - now abundant
```

but I dont know how to do this for a list.
I cannot merge the data frames into a single one, because the column names are not unique. I would need to do this step for me to be able to merge it into a data set and proceed. I'm forced to work with lists, something I am horrible with. 
Is there an easy way to do this? I am quite lost on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply()`

```
rename_col <- function(x){
  colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x),x[1,],sep="_")
  x[-1,]
}

#df_list as your list of data.frames
lapply(df_list,rename_col)
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in x[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions. Any fix to this?

Comment: @Skurup `df_list` needs to be a list where each element contains a data.frame. Is this happening with your data? Could you post some example data so that we can replicate the error?